# Customizing the hovertemplate in a scatter plot in plotly

Tags: plotly

I am plotting a scatter plot in plotly. So far no problem but I want to customize the text that appears while hovering. (I have done it in the past but now it is failing)

So I have a constant `Konstant` and the plot data is

```
data = [go.Scatter(x=list_t, y=list_post,mode='markers',name= "Post",
            hovertemplate = 
            '<b>Set: %{text}</b><br>'+
            '(%{x:.2f},%{y:.2f})',
            text=str(Konstant*x) ),
          go.Scatter(x=list_t, y=list_pred,mode='markers',name= "Pre"), 
    ]
```

My objective is that the text that appears when putting the mouse over is a string of the numerical result of multiplying the constant `Konstant` with the x value of the plot.

Right now what appears is literally `Set: %{text}` How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to actually verify the code since I don't know the data, but based on the example in the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#customizing-hover-text-with-a-hovertemplate), I think I need the text for the data.
I guessed that I wanted to use the x-axis data and multiply it by a constant to display the result as a string.

```
data = [go.Scatter(x=list_t, y=list_post,mode='markers',name= "Post",
            hovertemplate = 
            '<b>Set: %{text}</b><br>'+
            '(%{x:.2f},%{y:.2f})',
            text = [str(Konstant * x) for x in range(len(list_T))]),
          go.Scatter(x=list_t, y=list_pred,mode='markers',name= "Pre"), 
    ]
```